# how two check point if it falls on route direction between two points?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places, google-location-services

this a direction between two points (A) and (B) if i have new point (C) how can i check if point (C)  falls on the direction between (A) and (B)

[image: here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the Geometry library in the Google Maps API to determine if a point lies on or near a line. See example here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#isLocationOnEdge

For Android:

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

The isLocationOnEdge function is implemented here:

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java

Comment: i want a solution for android

Comment: @user8282703 I have updated the answer with link to android utility.

Comment: thank you, but it is a very complex code how can I use this method the second parameter takes a list of latlng polylines. must i draw polylines between two pionts and get latlng of this points ?

Comment: You will use the polyline of your route on which you want to find the point.